# if (X1 x X2 x...x Xn, T) is connected. then each (Xi, Ti) is connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let (Xi, Ti) be a topological space. Prove that if (X1 x X2 x...x Xn, T) is connected. then each (Xi, Ti) is connected.

Proof: Since (X1 x X2 x...x Xn, T) is connected, the space has only two clopen sets: the empty set and X1 x X2 x...x Xn iff each Xi is a clopen set or the empty set,i=1, 2, ..,n
Therefore each (Xi, Ti) is connected.

Could you please check this for me? I'm not sure about my proof. If it's not ok, could you please give me some ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Let (Xi, Ti) be a topological space. Prove that if (X1 x X2 x...x Xn, T) is compact. then each (Xi, Ti) is compact.

Comment: My proof: Assume that one of the (Xi,Ti) is not compact, then some of its open cover does not have a finite subcover, then...???

Comment: could anyone give me a hint on this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid that it’s not okay: you really haven’t said anything that justifies the conclusion that $X_1$, say, is connected, because you haven’t shown how connectedness of the product is related to connectedness of the factors. How does the fact that $X_1\times\ldots\times X_n$ is the only non-empty clopen set in the product actually imply that $X_1$ is the only non-empty clopen set in $X_1$, for instance?

HINT: Suppose that $H$ is a non-empty clopen subset of $X_k$ for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. What can you say about

$$\pi_k^{-1}[H]=\{\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in X_1\times\ldots\times X_n:x_k\in H\}\;,$$

where $\pi_k:X_1\times\ldots\times X_n\to X_k$ is the usual projection map?

Comment: π−1k[H]={⟨x1,…,xn⟩∈X1×…×Xn:xk∈H} is not connected??

Comment: @user110969: It might or might not be connected. Is it open in the product? Is it closed in the product?

Comment: it's both open and closed?

Comment: @user110969: It is indeed; do you see why?

Comment: because the product of open sets is open and the product of closed sets is closed and it has both properties

Comment: @user110969: Okay; you can think of it that way. You can also use the fact that each map $\pi_k$ is continuous, and the inverse image of an open set under a continuous map is open, and similarly for closed sets.

Comment: So you mean I can say: some Xk contains a proper clopen set, then its inverse image is also a clopen set which is the subset of  X1×…×Xn. This implies that (X1×…×Xn, T) is not connected ??

Comment: @user110969: That’s right. And from that it follows immediately that if the product **is** connected, then each of the factor spaces must also be connected.

Comment: So I just need to make a statement like what you've said above and the problem is done?

Comment: @user110969: Yes, assuming that you’ve put all of the pieces together in the right order and in such a way that the reader can see that you understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your proof as it's currently written.

---

One different approach is this: Suppose that $X_1$ were disconnected; then there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $U \cup V = X_1$. Then what can you say about the sets

$$U \times X_2 \times \dots \times X_n$$

and $$V \times X_2 \times \dots \times X_n ?$$

Comment: Then 
U×X2×⋯×Xn
and 
V×X2×⋯×Xn have proper clopen sets, so, they are not connected

Comment: @user110969 That's not really the direction I was going for. These are two non-empty open sets whose union is ____, whose intersection is ____, and so the original space is not connected, a contradiction.

Comment: whose union is X1, whose intersection is empty

Comment: @user110969 I meant to ask what the union of $U \times X_2 ... \times X_n$ and $V \times X_2 ... \times X_n$ is.

Comment: the union is X1×X2...×Xn??

Comment: @user110969 Exactly. This contradicts that $X_1 \times ... \times X_n$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach is that the projection map $\pi_i$ onto the $i-$th coordinate is a continuous map, so that it takes connected sets to connected sets. Then $$\pi_i (X_1 \times X_2 \times.....\times X_n)$$ =$X_i$ is connected, as the continuous image of the connected space $X_1 \times X_2 \times...\times X_n$